# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery - error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with getting the top selling product from my database. This is the code I have tried:

```
SELECT productid 
FROM soldvia 
GROUP BY productid 
HAVING SUM(noofitems) =  (SELECT MAX(SUM(noofitems))
                          FROM soldvia 
                          GROUP BY productid);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 68
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can write this as:

```
SELECT productid
FROM soldvia
GROUP BY productid
HAVING SUM(noofitems) = (SELECT TOP (1) SUM(noofitems)
                         FROM soldvia
                         GROUP BY productid
                         ORDER BY SUM(noofitems) DESC
                        );
```

The more typical way to write the query, though, uses `RANK()` or window functions:

```
SELECT productid
FROM (SELECT productid, SUM(noofitems) as numitems,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(noofitems) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM soldvia
      GROUP BY productid
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```